2d Particle Physics Optimizations
I am working on a particle physics simulation inspired by https://www.ventrella.com/Clusters/ and I want some advice on optimization.
I currently use a quad tree and thread pooling. However this causes issues. The core part of the simulation is that particles can affect each other like gravity. Unfortunately even when quads share edge particles the particles very obviously stop getting affected once fully over a quad border.
My question is what some alternative optimizations for this or are the improvements to be made with my current setup.
https://github.com/tizwarp/ppopccorn/ current source code its messy

I would suggest not using quad trees for moving objects, unless you are working with HUGE worlds, as maintenance and usability across borders tends to outweigh any gains. Use a simple grid for spacial partitioning instead.
